# unable to provide a input as "dot" in the textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have this code for  validating text field number.

This code works fine, but only problem is it does not allow me to enter `.`(dot) . 
My textfield is for amount, amount can be 222.234234 , or 222 
So what code i should add  in order to enable users to enter periods with the below scrits

```
function ValidateNum(input,event)
    {
        var keyCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        if((parseInt(keyCode)>=48 && parseInt(keyCode)<=57) || parseInt(keyCode)==08 ||  parseInt(keyCode)==09 || parseInt(keyCode)==127 )  
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

textfield

```
<input type="text" name="from_amount" onkeypress="return ValidateNum(this,event)" id="from_amount" placeholder="    Type to convert" />`
```

So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Allow `keyCode` 190. Although you have to be careful the "Shift" key isn't being pressed as well, which would result in ">"

Comment: And if you're using `jQuery`, you shouldn't need to normalize the `event` or the `keyCode`.

Comment: Don't try to prevent key events - it leads just to bad UX! Instead, validate the *value* of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not validate the entire string instead of validating each inputted character?

Do this:

```
//I am assuming that input is the text element
function validateNumber(input) {
    //newer browsers should have .trim(). Otherwise you can do something like:
    //   input.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(input.value.trim()); 
}
```

Will your current validation-function account for the case when a use enters only the `.` character? What about multiple `.` characters? How about the value `123.`, or `1.43.3`, or `1..2`? It looks like the current function only validates the inputted character without looking at the context of that character (i.e., what surrounds it).

On another note, consider using something like jQuery or binding to the input element instead of using the `onkeypress` attribute. That method of binding is more-or-less deprecated and not recommended. Also this method of validation prevents keypress events which can be confusing. It's probably better to validate the entire form after they have filled it in, or mark the text-field as invalid as they are writing in it.

You can also use the HTML5 `type` value of `number` instead of `text` to constrain what the user can input into that field. That way you wouldn't even have to do any validation.

Comment: Can you give the full script inside `<script>..</script>`

Comment: @i updated my question. Please give me full code, i could not understand your code. I am new in javascript

Comment: @Ashutosh There's really not much more to give you. I've updated my answer; it should be pretty straightforward. There is no need to pass in the `event`.

Comment: @Ashutosh It would be the same, except you wouldn't be passing in `event`; just `this`. But I cannot stress enough how this method really isn't recommended.

Comment: i used this `<input type="text" name="from_amount" onkeypress="return validateNumber(this)" id="from_amount" placeholder="    Type to convert" />`  But your code is not allowing me to presss any code. Why?

Comment: I mean,   your code is not allowing me to enter any keyboard keys.

Comment: @Ashutosh Probably because it returns `false` all the time. You have to debug it to see what it's doing. Like I said before, this is probably not the best way to validate.

Comment: its difficult for me , i am quitting this validation. its out of my head.I am not for nothing. I accepted your answer because you spent your time for me. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Keycode for `.` is 190.
You can check this list here-> http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: This doesn't cover whether the Shift key is being pressed (which results in a different character)